# How can I use count instead of not exists in a query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, boat and reservation, and this is their schema:

```
boat: bname (string), color (string), rating (integer)
reservation: sname (string), bname (string), day (string)
```

I am trying to find the days where ONLY red boat are reserved and nothing else. I wrote the query to do so using NOT EXISTS but can't figure out how to write it with COUNT. This is using sqlite3

This is a homework assignment and I am not looking for an answer, but rather looking for advice as to how to approach this. I was able narrow it and get ONLY the days when there are a mix of red boats and other colored boats, but not sure how to approach it from there.

So for example, if there are red boats reserved on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday but there is also a green boat reserved on tuesday, my query will return Tuesday, but since I can't use NOT IN or NOT EXISTS, I am not sure how to move on from there. Here is the query in question:

```
SELECT distinct R.day from reservation R, boat b 
WHERE r.bname = b.bname and b.color = 'red' AND 
(SELECT count(*) from reservation R2, boat B 
WHERE R2.bname = B.bname and COLOR != 'red' AND R.day = R2.day group by R2.day);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: "Not exists" means that the count is zero.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would answer the question like this:

```
select r.day
from reservation r join
     boat b 
     on r.bname = b.bname
group by r.day
having min(b.color) = 'red' and max(b.color) = 'red';
```

Do note: you should never use commas in the `from` clause.  You should always use proper, explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid this won't work in my case. We were told to specifically use COUNT and reproduce the behavior of NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.day FROM reservation r, boat b 
  WHERE r.bname = b.bname AND b.color = 'red' AND 
    (SELECT count(*) from reservation R2
       WHERE r.day = R2.day) = 
    (SELECT count(*) from reservation R2, boat B2 
       WHERE R2.bname = B2.bname AND b2.color = 'red' AND r.day = R2.day group by R2.day);
```